# extract data in svg file and export in excel automatically

Tags: java, vba

suppose if there are 20 svg files with the same components but with different values, I need to extract the content of transistor(model number) alone and automatically export them to excel sheet. Kindly help. TIA
  [[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wyQGk.gif][1]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  We are a question-and-answer site, not a coders-for-hire service. Please narrow your question down to a specific coding question that would be on-topic for this site.  See: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236) and [How to ask a good question when I'm not sure what I'm looking for?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262527/how-to-ask-a-good-question-when-im-not-sure-what-im-looking-for)

Comment: open the svg file using a text editor. look for the data that you need in cleartext. if it is there, then there may be a way. can you post the svg file? or a link to it

Comment: i have added the image in my question. kindly view it as a svg file . As this format is not supported here

Comment: you need to use an OCR (optical character recognition) software to read the text in a picture. you cannot view a gif file as an svg file. svg file is text based. it contains instructions on how to draw the picture that it shows. it also shows text, unless the text is drawn as a graphic. these instructions are decoded and drawn by the viewer that you are using. a gif file is total gibberish when viewed with a text editor.

Comment: i ask you again, open the svg file with a text editor and do a search for "BUZ74"

Comment: does any adobe software support OCR? if so how  extract that particular data and store it in a file?

Comment: i checked the web. found a few copies of the schematic that you posted. all were gif and png files. i could not find any in svg format. http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-8wra2rBCA-Y/UFi5UzImSeI/AAAAAAAAAkY/4lFZDI2f5FI/s1600/Car_Interior_Lights_Delay_Circuit_Diagram.GIF ran it through https://onlineocr.net/ got nothing useful

Comment: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Electrical_symbols_library.svg

Comment: if you download that svg file, then add **.txt** on the end of the filename. then open the file, it should open with notepad, you will see what i am talking about.  it is a text file, you can search for "100ma" and you will find a couple of instances of "100ma".  ... do the same with the schematic that you have, and check if the data you seek is in any recognizable pattern. ( maybe in the same spot in each file. or next to the same keyword ...)

Answer (score 0):

your best bet is to do this manually. there is no programmable way to tell which part of the picture contains the data of interest.